# flask migrate automatically changing database

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, database-migration, alembic

I'm new to Flask and Flask-Migrate.
When running `python manage.py db migrate -m "explanation"`, whatever change I made to models.py gets automatically applied to the database (in this case, adding a column to some table).

I thought changes were only supposed to be applied after running `python manage.py db upgrade`?

Also, in the above example, the migration file contains two functions: `upgrade` and `downgrade`. However, they are both empty... Aren't they supposed to be include the changes I wanted to apply to the database?

I've read the documentation and it seems to contradict what is actually happening. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not how `Flask-Migrate` works. The `migrate` command discover and generate schema changes, writing it to a file with the migration description code, with a `upgrade` and a `downgrade` functions.

The database is changed with the `python manage.py db upgrade` command.

I suspect you have something dropping your database and recreating it when you run the `migrate` command. Something like:

```
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
```

It'll recreate the database, probably before `Flask-Migrate` is able to analyze the schema.

Comment: I think that was it, thank you for the help. Do you have a good resource you'd recommend, to learn more about the library? I can't find a good tutorial / post about it.
It seems like there are a few kinks to SQLAlchemy- e.g., it doesn't detect certain small changes to the type of a column. I'd like to learn how to inspect the upgrade script and edit it as necessary...

Comment: Yes, `Flask-Migrate` is just a small `alembic` wrapper. Read `alembic` docs to understand how it works. http://alembic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/